# How can I calculate the Focal Length of my rendered image in a ray tracer (Let's say PBRT)?

Tags: raytracing, 3d-reconstruction, 3d-rendering, fieldofview

Actually, I have rendered 3 input images of a sphere with different light directions in PBRT.
As the next step of the process, I am going to compute surface normals of this sphere, so I need to put the Focal length value in my formula.
All that I now is that I have the value of Field of View (FOV) in my PBRT input files which is 45.
The dimensions of the whole image is 32*32 and the dimensions of the sphere in the image is 26*26.
How can I compute the exact amount of the Focal length using this information?

Comment: You need to put focal length into your formula to calculate surface normals? Wat? For a sphere you can calculate the surface normal by taking the vector from the centre to any point on the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use **perspective** without knowing the focal length in **3D** graphics. It is also called `z_near` and it is the distance from camera origin (point from which you cast the rays) to the **projection plane**. Look at this:

[image: img]

where: Point `P` near `Camera` label is the **focal point** and the blue rectangle labeled `Screen(z_near)` is the **projection plane**. The **focal length** is perpendicular distance of this point to the plane.

**PS. boyfarrell** is right you do not need **focal length** for **normal** computations. It does not make sense. You could need it to compute some physic process like **pupil size** etc but not for **normals**.